# change color of jstree node

Tags: jstree

Has anybody ever tried to change the color of jstree particular node using types plugin? And also I want to avoid click event on that node.
I need to do this to prevent users from selecting the same node.

Comment: What do you mean by color? Color of text, background? Could you be more specific what you want user to prevent from? Sample code would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example on how to change color of any node being clicked:

```
$(function() // document ready
{
    $("#my_jstree_instance a").live("click", function(e) 
    {
        nodeid = $(this).parent().attr("id").split("_")[1];
        $("#node_"+nodeid+" >a").css("color","red");
    }
}
```