# Change Color of jstree node with json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jstree

My jstree bind with following json format comes from web service..i want to change node color programmatically.

```
   $("#divCourseTree").jstree({
                 'core': {
                     'data': {
                         'type': "POST",
                         "async": "true",
                         'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         'url': "../WebService/BranchLocation.asmx/BindCourseTreeData",
                         'data': "{}",
                         'dataType': 'JSON',
                         'data': function (node) {

                          },
                         'success': function (retvel) {
                             var r = [];
                             var data = eval("(" + retvel.d + ")");
                             for (var key in data) {
                                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                                     var y = data[key].id;
                                     r.push(y);
                                     $("#" + y + " a").addClass('.Selected');

                                 }
                             }

                         }

                     }
                   }
                 });
```

Please help for this

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352329/change-color-of-jstree-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
             var r = [];

             $("#divCourseTree").jstree({
                 'core': {
                     'data': {
                         'type': "POST",
                         "async": "true",
                         'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         'url': "../WebService/BranchLocation.asmx/BindCourseTreeData",
                         'data': "{}",
                         'dataType': 'JSON',
                         'data': function (node) {

                          },
                         'success': function (retvel) {

                             var data = eval("(" + retvel.d + ")");
                             for (var key in data) {
                                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                                     var y = data[key].id;
                                     var t = data[key].Temp;

                                     if (t == '1')
                                     {
                                         r.push(y);
                                     }


                                     //$("#" + y + " a").addClass('.Selected');

                                 }
                             }


                         }

                     }
                   }
             }).bind("loaded.jstree", function () {
                 for (var i in r) {
                     $("#" + r[i] + " >a").css("color", "green");
                 }


             }).on("open_node.jstree", function () {
                 for (var i in r) {
                     $("#" + r[i] + " >a").css("color", "green");
                 }


             });

         });
```